# Bootstrap navbar not responsive (Collapses immediately)

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN stack and I'm using bootstrap for styling. I didn't touch any of the original code just added some routing and ngIf statements. All of a sudden the navbar isn't responsive anymore. When I click on the navbar-toggler the navbar expands and collapses immediately.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VeganGent</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/producten">Producten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/registreren">Registreren</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profiel">Profiel</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="onLogoutClick()" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sounds like click event is attached twice. Is this the only navbar with `navbarsExample04` id? You can check the events attached to element and see where they come from.

Comment: So how do I check this? Pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: It is the only navbar I have.

Comment: If you are using Chrome -> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

Comment: Don't really find anything usefull

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was using an older jquery link. So updated it and everything worked fine.